# ASP.NET Core Empty Template add User object

Tags: asp.net-core

When I create an ASP.NET Core web app project, it by default has the logged in user in the top right corner of the page. Problem is that when I make an ASP.NET Core empty project, the user object is not available?

My question is how do I add the user object to a empty template?

In case it is relevant, I need this to get the current logged in Windows user, I don't need any user management, just need to identify who is logged in.

Comment: If you want to add Windows Authentication in Existing project, you can refer to this [Docs](https://www.bizstream.com/blog/how-to-set-up-windows-authentication-with-net-5/).

Comment: @XinranShen thank you, sorry for the delay been swamped.  this works with a few modifications.  problem is i cant seem to find where to get the actual user.  in the non min proj templates this is included as the user property of the pagemodel.  how do i get the actual user logged in from the negotiate package?